# md-autocomplete does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-material

I was trying to use angular material's md-autocomplete , I have the directive specified like

```
  <md-autocomplete
    md-selected-item="mainctrl.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="mainctrl.search_term"
    md-items="item in mainctrl.search(mainctrl.search_term)"
    md-item-text="item"
    md-delay="500"
    md-min-length="4"
    placeholder="Type to search">
    <span md-highlight-text="mainctrl.search_term">{{item}}</span>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

And in the controller I have defined the search function like

```
this.search = function(term){
  var result = [];
  Search.findValues(term,this.details.data,result).then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  });
};
```

The Search service is as given below :

```
  .service('Search',function($q){
    var self = this;
    var deferred;

   self.findValues = function(term,obj,result){

  //if(!deferred){
    deferred = $q.defer();
  //}
  if(typeof obj === 'object'){
    angular.forEach(obj,function(v,k){
      self.findValues(term,v,result)
    });
    deferred.resolve(result);
  } else{

    if(typeof obj!='number'&& typeof obj!='boolean'){
      var res = obj.search(term);
      if(res!=-1){
        result.push(obj);
      }
    }
  }
  return deferred.promise;
} ;
return self ;
```

});

I am getting the desired result , But for some reason I am getting this following error ,

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at g (angular-material.min.js:271)
at r (angular-material.min.js:271)
at processQueue (angular.js:13189)
at angular.js:13205
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14401)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14217)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
at angular.js:16232
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4905)
at angular.js:5285
```

Answer (score 4):

The search function actually returns undefined so just wrap it in a promise.

I simplified the functions and used angular's $filter as a Search-Service.

```
search ( term ) {
  var q = this.$q.defer();
  this.findValues( term, this.data ).then( function ( res ) {
    q.resolve( res );
  } );
  return q.promise;
}

findValues ( term, obj ) {
  var deferred = this.$q.defer();
  deferred.resolve( this.$filter( 'filter' )( obj, term ) );
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I found this article on promises very helpful:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises

You might also want to look into your Search-Service, as your promise never resolves or rejects if `obj ==='undefined'`

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this error, try updating your angular material and this will error will be gone. (I updated mine one to 0.9.8)